# How could I web scrape the list of stock symbols from this page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use Beautiful Soup to web scrape the stock ticker symbols from this page: https://www.barchart.com/stocks/top-100-stocks/top

When I output soup.find_all(), I can't find any of the ticker symbols (e.g. "SBOW", "SPLP", "NOTV" etc.)

How would I be able to web scrape them from this page using beautiful soup?
If BS doesn't work, would Selenium be a better choice?

EDIT: Here's what I tried.

```
headers = {
        'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36"
        }

    data = requests.get(f'https://www.barchart.com/stocks/top-100-stocks/top?viewName=technical', headers=headers)
    soup = bs(data.content, 'html.parser')

    text = soup.find_all()
    print(text)
```

Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), and show your code. Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [**minimal reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: See the edit for an example.

Comment: You have to provide the tag name which you want to find in find_all.  Use chrome Dev tool to inspect the page properly and find the tag which contain the desired data. Then pass it into find_all

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to your question**

The website which you want to scrape is dynamically loaded. Using, chrome dev tools, you can find this API `https://www.barchart.com/proxies/core-api/v1/quotes/get`. Make the requests using get method and pass the headers and params along with it to download the page. You will get the text which is in json format. From here, your python skills comes into play.

**Note:** You don't even need the Beautiful Soup bcoz the data is in json format.

**Code**

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.barchart.com',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"',
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'x-xsrf-token': 'eyJpdiI6IlViRjViY2NWdW1pMDR1ZFQvS05vSFE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiTXdiK3NFYmdYN01CT2lKYTF4WWN4TFFJbkYwSndvMnJ2dFNPWmltS0FBMkphNmFGK3ZhWWVZb002dC8xZXNoNiIsIm1hYyI6IjkyNmZiMWUzYjA0OWE3NDQ0ZWUyMjZjNTJkZjMyMzRmY2E2NGE3MGRlY2E3ZGFlMTIxYTU2YzQ0OGFjNjZiY2EifQ==',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://www.barchart.com/stocks/top-100-stocks/top',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cookie': 'bcFreeUserPageView=0; _gcl_au=1.1.1809752935.1624440846; _ga=GA1.2.1705212203.1624440846; _gid=GA1.2.249464456.1624440846; usprivacy=1---; __qca=P0-570424811-1624440850998; __aaxsc=2; _admrla=2.0-16fb275c-98a2-9e82-4100-5faeb001fb9e; __gads=ID=55a6051647f1bdf3:T=1624547484:S=ALNI_MbukiaaihfTaO5LT9RiO3l33V4WgQ; market=eyJpdiI6IjVGTVZ2NVpndnNSNDRyTE1OSXBFMlE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVFh5UlFCSWdjWWp2ZXFrS3pxUWVDZz09IiwibWFjIjoiYjNkNzJjNzEzOTAzNzIxMmI4NzE5MDBiNzY4NDhhMjA2MmE5NmUzNmIzY2ZjY2VmNGIxNzhhZTZkMjlhYTM5YSJ9; IC_ViewCounter_www.barchart.com=2; aasd=6%7C1624641991103; _awl=2.1624642032.0.4-dca25043-16fb275c98a29e8241005faeb001fb9e-6763652d617369612d6561737431-60d611ea-0; laravel_token=eyJpdiI6IjZUNTlyc0h3RWRnSy9Gb3FibXJFRVE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiTVFBa05QZGVxb2thd3NDb1IrOWw2SVk1VDJ4RWE0RWR5QitkOWtKcStOSS9XVlFNazQxdUdCZ2FyVytZa0w2aWM3NFNhM2lzZ1JFWWhCeW1aT2xoSEY3THNPb3RtbE4wOWhLYXBDTzJvZ2ZCcHlNenFhOE4zb3ZTRFl6SzNkTkpCZCt1R0x2M3pwTHRPVm5NeW5Sa2ZpZHppY1VvK2pWUFhwNzVhUUVsMTlVcXJmS2xjN1RRVWZxaldRZ0xOeGlHQ3NHYjFmc2pGd0x2OGlZYVprZkUwUVdZTjVmelpEbmZBWURRWmhTTnZyZk0rNkJzMTNJUHJaNjR1enA2WXlaRCIsIm1hYyI6IjQ3Yzg0OTcyZjI4OTM5ODg0Yzk4NTI4NTVjZjZlYjkzZDUzYjIwOWIyMDJjODU0MGYzZThjY2FiODc2ZmQ5NjcifQ%3D%3D; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IlViRjViY2NWdW1pMDR1ZFQvS05vSFE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiTXdiK3NFYmdYN01CT2lKYTF4WWN4TFFJbkYwSndvMnJ2dFNPWmltS0FBMkphNmFGK3ZhWWVZb002dC8xZXNoNiIsIm1hYyI6IjkyNmZiMWUzYjA0OWE3NDQ0ZWUyMjZjNTJkZjMyMzRmY2E2NGE3MGRlY2E3ZGFlMTIxYTU2YzQ0OGFjNjZiY2EifQ%3D%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Inh3S2YwREN5RElrelI1ZU9SL0Qza3c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiajU4eEV6ZjZ6UTJWNzJIeFh2UXRJN2h4Wmw5UnRmUk4wdU5LWGFYNUJFTTdsRllvRnlFL0hPSFR2dEg3RGlpcyIsIm1hYyI6IjNmOWUwMGI3ODM0ZDMwYjc4OWI4YTRhZDlmMjQyYzg4YjI2Mjk5MWE0ZmU2NTFmMmY1MTlkNmViMGY0ZDFkOTUifQ%3D%3D',
}

params = (
    ('list', 'stocks.us.weighted_alpha.advances'),
    ('fields', 'symbol,symbolName,weightedAlpha,currentRankUsTop100,previousRank,lastPrice,priceChange,percentChange,highPrice1y,lowPrice1y,percentChange1y,tradeTime,symbolCode,hasOptions,symbolType'),
    ('orderBy', 'weightedAlpha'),
    ('orderDir', 'desc'),
    ('meta', 'field.shortName,field.type,field.description'),
    ('hasOptions', 'true'),
    ('page', '1'),
    ('limit', '100'),
    ('raw', '1'),
)

response = s.get('https://www.barchart.com/proxies/core-api/v1/quotes/get', headers=headers, params=params)
print(response.text)
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: He is using requests module to make the call

Comment: Thanks Abhishek, Initially, he hadn't posted the code. As per his action, I have modified my answer as well.

Comment: @Shivam Thanks for your response. When I pasted and ran this code, the print statement has a blank output. Did you get something else on your end?

Comment: @AlanN, I have edited the code please let me know if it works for you.